# Calabash no colors in output

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I have a Android device connected to my PC.
Running a calabash test I use the following command:

```
calabash-android run <NAME>.apk features/<NAME>.feature
```

Doing so I always get the following error even so I have ANSICON installed.

> *** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows

There are also no **colors** (using MINGW32 on a 64bit-win having ANSICON installed running it with -p and -i).

> $ ansicon.exe --help ANSICON by Jason Hood .
>   Version 1.66 (21 September, 2013).  Freeware.
>   http://ansicon.adoxa.vze.com/

How can I make this work?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is your problem still exists? @lony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this, but I found this blog post that writes about the same problem http://qastuffs.blogspot.dk/2011/02/how-to-install-ansicon-for-cucumber-to.html
So it could be worth a try.

Copied from the blog

> Anyway, here are the steps on how to install ansicon.exe:
>
> 1. Download and unzip the file from https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads
> 2. open cmd and navigate to the unzipped folder
> 3. Navigate to x64 (if you have a 64 bit machine) otherwise navigate to x86
> 4. Type ansicon.exe -h and you will get the following: D:\Data\ansicon\x86>ansicon.exe -h ANSICON by Jason Hood . Version
>      1.32 (22 December, 2010).  Freeware. http://ansicon.adoxa.cjb.net/
>
> Process ANSI escape sequences in Win32 console programs.
>
> ansicon -i|I | -u|U ansicon [-m[]] [-p | -e|E string | -t|T [file(s)]
>   | program [args]]
>
> -i            install - add ANSICON to the AutoRun entry (implies
>   -p)   -u            uninstall - remove ANSICON from the AutoRun entry   -I -U         use local machine instead of current user   -m            use grey on black ("monochrome") or  as default color   -p
>   hook into the parent process   -e            echo string   -E
>   echo string, don't append newline   -t            display files ("-"
>   for stdin), combined as a single stream   -T            display files,
>   name first, blank line before and after   program       run the
>   specified program   nothing       run a new command processor, or
>   display stdin if redirected
>
> is one or two hexadecimal digits; please use "COLOR /?" for details.
>   5. Execute 'ansicon.exe -i' to install and add ansicon to your Windows
>   6. Run your cucumber 0.10.0 test and you should  get the coloured output result on Windows